# Pipe '.' dot causes trouble in glm call

Tags: r, dplyr

dplyr's pipe does not pass the name of objects passed down the chain. This is well known. However, it leads to unexpected complications after you fit a `glm` model. Functions using `glm` objects expect the call to contain the correct name of the object containing data.

```r
    #sample data
    p_load(ISLR)
    mydata = ISLR::Default

    #fit glm
    fitted=
    mydata %>% 
      select(default, income) %>%
      glm(default~.,data=.,family=binomial) 

    #dot in call
    fitted$call

    #pscl's pR2 pseudo r2 function does not work
    p_load(pscl)
    pR2(fitted)
```

How to fix this behavior?
I want to keep using pipes, including the `select` function. I also want to obtained a glm objected in `fitted` than can be used with `pR2` or other function that need a working call.

One can re-arrange the data-preprocessing into the glm call, but it takes away the elegance of the code.

```r
fitted=
  glm(default~.,
      data=mydata %>%
        select(default, income),
      family=binomial)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This is because the `.` has a special meaning in a `glm` formula, i.e. to fit the model to all variables contained in the dataset `data` except the dependend variable.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty common problem. You already know the solution, don't pipe into `glm`. Assign to a intermediate object. `mydata_glm <- mydata %>% ..... ; glm(...., data = mydata_glm)`

Comment: @eastclintw00d, while that's true, I don't think that's the issue here (the issue is the `.` for data, not the `.` in the formula.

Comment: Both `DescTools::PseudoR2()` updates the call via `stats::update`. It does not find the data, looking for `.`. Yes, can have an intermediate objects, but I want something more elegant, and I want code to be as minimal as possible. I think I want too much.

Comment: He who lives by the pipe, dies by the pipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Since you are explicitly writing out all the variables in the `select` anyways you can just as easily write them out in the formula instead and get rid of the `select` -- you can keep the `select` if you like but it does seem pointless if the variables are already explicitly given in the formula. Then this works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(pscl)
library(ISLR)

fitted <- Default %$% glm(default ~ income, family=binomial)

fitted %>% pR2
```

**2)** Another possibilty is to invert it so that instead of putting `glm` inside the pipe put the pipe inside `glm`:

```
fitted <- 
  glm(default ~ ., data = Default %>% select(income, default), family = binomial)

fitted %>% pR2
```

**3)** A third approach is to generate the `formula` argument of `glm` rather than the `data` argument.

```
fitted <- Default %>% 
  select(starts_with("inc")) %>% 
  names %>% 
  reformulate("default") %>%
  glm(data = Default, family = binomial)

fitted %>% pR2
```

Replace the `glm` line with this if it is important that the `Call:` line in the output look nice.

```
{ do.call("glm", list(., data = quote(Default), family = quote(binomial))) }
```

or using purrr:

```
{ invoke("glm", list(., data = expr(Default), family = expr(binomial))) }
```

Comment: (1) `select` can use wildcards (e.g., `starts_with()`, `ends_with()`, `contains()`), or be replaced by `select_if`. It may look pointless in the minimal example, but in general, it isn't.

Comment: What is helpful though is the pointing out the two approaches: either fixing formula OR data works.

Comment: Have added (3).

Comment: This is probably the best possible solution given all the constraints. I forgot about `reformulate` -- really useful here. Great job!

Comment: Related issue, maybe worth a new Question: using map: 
`Default %>% group_by(student) %>% nest %>%
  mutate(model=map(data,glm,formula=formul,family='binomial')) %>%
  mutate(pr2=map(model,pR2))`