# purrr:map and glm - issues with call

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

This issue is related to [Pipe '.' dot causes trouble in glm call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917346/pipe-dot-causes-trouble-in-glm-call).

purrr:map is wonderful for subgroup analysis and/or model comparison. However, when using `glm`, the call is messed up and causing issues, e.g. when computing pseudo-R2s. The reason is that `update` doesn't work with the ugly `call`, and thus `pscl::pR2` cannot compute the log-likelihood of the base model.

```r
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

#sample data
pacman::p_load(ISLR)
mydata = ISLR::Default

#nest data, students and non-students
Default_nested = Default %>% group_by(student) %>% nest 

#fit glms
formul= default ~income+balance

glms = Default_nested %>% 
  mutate(model=map(data,glm,formula=formul,family='binomial')) 

#pscl::pR2 throwing error
pacman::p_load(pscl)
glms %>% mutate(pr2=map(model,pR2))
```

Now we can take a look at the first submodel. The call looks strange (formula=..1) even though formula contains the right formula.

```
> glms$model[[1]]$call
.f(formula = ..1, family = "binomial", data = .x[[i]])
> glms$model[[1]]$formula
default ~ income + balance
> glms$model[[1]]$data
# A tibble: 7,056 x 3
   default balance income
   <fct>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 No         730. 44362.
```

What is the cleanest way to be able to use pscl::pR2 when you have many (more than 2 in this example) glm objects in your tibble?

**Edit:**

Overview of solution strategies:

**(A)** *"fix" the glm object*, so that `update` can be applied to it:

```r
glms %>% mutate(model = map(model,function(x){x$call = call2("glm",formula=x$formula,data=quote(Default),family='binomial');x})) %>%
  mutate(pr2=map(model,pR2)) %>% unnest(pr2)
```

This 'runs', however, the computed R2 is off. So this solution strategy is probably a dead-end.

**(B)** Write a *wrapper* for `glm, as proposed by Artem. This should work fine. Downside: the calls look ugly.

I expanded on Artem's proposed solution to create `glm3`.

```r
glm3 <- function(formula,data,family) {  
  eval(rlang::expr( glm(!!rlang::enexpr(data),
                        formula=!!formula,
                        family=!!family ) ))}

glms3 <- Default_nested %>% mutate( model=map(data,glm3,formula=formul,family='binomial'),pr2=map(model,pR2) )
glms3 %>% unnest(pr2)
```

**(C)** In this particular case (pseudo R2s), simply write a better *pseudo-r2 function*. Since it's probably the only major statistic that doesn't work within purrr::map, this may actually make sense. I put together the `psr2glm` function.

```r
psr2glm=function(glmobj){

  L.base=
    logLik(
      glm(formula = reformulate('1',gsub( " .*$", "", deparse(glmobj$formula) )),
          data=glmobj$data,
          family = glmobj$family))

  n=length(glmobj$residuals)

  L.full=logLik(glmobj)
  D.full <- -2 * L.full
  D.base <- -2 * L.base
  G2 <- -2 * (L.base - L.full)

  return(data.frame(McFadden = 1-L.full/L.base, 
                    CoxSnell = 1 - exp(-G2/n),
                    Nagelkerke = (1 - exp((D.full - D.base)/n))/(1 - exp(-D.base/n))))

}
```

It works:

```r
glms = Default_nested %>% 
  mutate(model=map(data,glm,formula=formul,family='binomial')) 
glms %>% mutate(pr2=map(model,psr2glm)) %>% unnest(pr2)
```

I consider proposing changes to DescTools:::PseudoR2, however, I first need to check if the solution is general.

The key to this idea is to skip `update` and instead directly call `glm`. All required information pieces are within the glm object, even within purrr::map.
Nice side effect of using psr2glm: unnest's output looks nice.

**(D)** Change either `glm` or `update`. Given that the glm object actually contains all necessary information, one could consider the observed behavior a bug. So it should be fixed in base R.

Comment: Check out the (unresolved) discussion [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/407)

Comment: Thanks. It's unresolved and closed. The limitation of the tidy dialect.

Comment: `glms$model[[1]]$call=glm(1~1,Default,family = 'binomial')$call

glms$model[[2]]$call=glm(1~1,Default,family = 'binomial')$call

glms %>% mutate(pr2=map(model,pR2)) %>% unnest(pr2)` 

"works" ... you can put the same call into each nested model ... and you get the results. But this is super hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to define a wrapper for `glm()` that puts data directly inside the call by manually constructing the expression and then evaluating it:

```
glm2 <- function(.df, ...) {
  eval(rlang::expr(glm(!!rlang::enexpr(.df),!!!list(...)))) }

glms <- Default_nested %>%
    mutate( model = map(data,glm2,formula=formul,family="binomial"),
            pr2   = map(model,pscl::pR2) )
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   student data                 model  pr2      
#   <fct>   <list>               <list> <list>   
# 1 No      <tibble [7,056 × 3]> <glm>  <dbl [6]>
# 2 Yes     <tibble [2,944 × 3]> <glm>  <dbl [6]>
```

**Validation:**

```
## Perform the computation by hand and ensure that it's identical to glms$pr2
glm(Default_nested$data[[1]], formula=default~income+balance, family="binomial") %>%
  pscl::pR2() %>% identical( glms$pr2[[1]] )     # TRUE
glm(Default_nested$data[[2]], formula=default~income+balance, family="binomial") %>%
  pscl::pR2() %>% identical( glms$pr2[[2]] )     # TRUE
```

Comment: Great idea. Just why can't glm2 also quote formula and family?

Comment: `glm3 <- function(.df,formula,family) {  
  eval(rlang::expr( glm(!!rlang::enexpr(.df),
                        formula=!!formula,
                        family=!!family ) ))}

glms3 <- Default_nested %>% mutate( model=map(data,glm3,formula=formul,family='binomial'),pr2=map(model,pR2) )
glms3 %>% unnest(pr2)` this wrapper seems to work

Comment: @inferator: Yes, that's precisely how one would do it. I modified my answer to show how `...` can be used to cover all additional parameters to `glm()`, including `formula` and `family`.

Comment: Nice. I guess that warrants an acceptance, though I would still appreciate alternative solutions. Wrapping `glm` is just one way to solve this.