# R sometimes fails to evaluate expressions parsed from strings

Tags: r, expression, purrr

I have a massive dataframe where I need to create "lagged" variables and compare them with former time points. As this process needs to be variable, I've chosen to write my own functions which create these lagged variables (not included here).

As I use GLM's, I want to use the stepAIC function and before I start writing tenth of "lag01 + lag02..." I wanted to create another function (modelfiller) which creates these strings according to my parameters and then I use `string2lang` to make them expressions.

This mostly works but there is one issue which I cannot get my head around.

As you can see in the reprex full.model can be created when I only use `y~x+lag01+lag02`. If I use `modelfiller("y", 2, "x", "lag")` at location 1 and 3 it also works. But the moment I put `modelfiller("y", 2, "x", "lag")` at location 2 in the code (within the stepAIC glm) it creates the following error message:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `GLM_AIC`.
x object '.x' not found
i Input `GLM_AIC` is `purrr::map(...)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: group = "a".
```

I have also tried  `as.formula` with & without  `eval`, but it caused the same issue.

```
group <- c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10),  rep("c", 10))
order <- c(seq(1:10), seq(1:10), seq(1:10))
x <- c(runif(30))
y <- c(runif(30))

df <- data.frame(group, order, x, y)

df <- df  %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(group, order) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(lag01 = dplyr::lag(x, n=1),
                lag02 = dplyr::lag(x, n=2)) %>% 
  tidyr::drop_na() 


modelfiller = function(depPar, maxlag, indepPar, str) {
  varnames = list()
  for (i in seq(1:maxlag)) {
    varnames[i] = paste0(str, stringr::str_pad(i, width = 2, pad = "0"))
  }
  varnames = paste0(varnames, collapse="+")
  varnames = paste(indepPar, varnames, sep = "+")
  return(paste(depPar, varnames, sep = "~"))
}


full.model <- df %>%
  tidyr::nest(- group) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    # Perform GLM calculation on each group and then a step-wise model selection based on AIC
    GLM = purrr::map(
      data, ~ lm(data = .x, 
                 # Location 1 - Working
                 str2lang(modelfiller("y", 2, "x", "lag"))
                 #y~x+lag01+lag02
                 )),
    GLM_AIC = purrr::map(
      data, ~ MASS::stepAIC(glm(data = .x,
                                # Location 2 - NOT Working
                                str2lang(modelfiller("y", 2, "x", "lag"))
                                #y~x+lag01+lag02
                                )
                            ,direction = "both", trace = FALSE, k = 2,
                            scope = list(
                              lower = lm(data = .x, 
                                         y ~ 1),
                              upper = glm(data = .x,
                                          # Location 3 - Working
                                          str2lang(modelfiller("y", 2, "x", "lag"))
                                          #y~x+lag01+lag02
                                          )
                            )))
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `glm` stores the name of the variable used to reference the data, and `stepAIC` then attempts to retrieve this name and evaluate it to access the data, but gets confused about which environment the variable was defined in. To demonstrate, I'm going to simplify your code to

```
mdl <- str2lang(modelfiller("y", 2, "x", "lag"))      # This is your y~x+lag01+lag02
dfn <- df %>% tidyr::nest( data = c(-group) )         # First step of your %>% chain
glms <- purrr::map( dfn$data, ~glm(data = .x, mdl) )  # Construct the models

# Examine glms to observe that
# Call:  glm(formula = mdl, data = .x)    <--- glm() remembers that the data is in .x

# but stepAIC is not properly aware of where .x
# is defined and behaves effectively as
MASS::stepAIC( glms[[1]] )                            # Error: object '.x' not found
```

**Option 1**

One workaround is to [manually construct the expression that contains the data and then evaluate it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57528229/300187):

```
glm2 <- function(.df, ...) {
  eval(rlang::expr(glm(!!rlang::enexpr(.df),!!!list(...)))) }

glms2 <- purrr::map( dfn$data, ~glm2(data = .x, mdl) )  # Same as above, but with glm2
MASS::stepAIC( glms2[[1]] )                             # Now works
```

Changing `glm` to `glm2` in your problematic spot makes your code work too. The down side is that the `Call:` then remembers the entire data frame, which can be problematic if they are very large.

**Option 2**

Another alternative is to replace the `purrr` call with a `for` loop, which helps maintain the calling frames assumed by `stepAIC`, thus guiding it to where the data is defined

```
# This fails with Error: object '.x' not found
purrr::map( dfn$data, ~MASS::stepAIC(glm(data=.x, mdl), direction="both") )

# This works
for( mydata in dfn$data )
    MASS::stepAIC(glm(data=mydata, mdl), direction="both")
```

The advantage here is not needing to store the entire data frame inside the call. The disadvantage is that you effectively lose access to what `purrr` does to streamline the code.

Comment: Great work! I used your option 1 and it works nicely in the test set. 
But it is interesting that the first glm in stepAIC gets confused but the later one for the upper boundary does not.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with a "follow" up question. 

As said I use your glm2 function, but as I have a lot of models which I create I wanted to make the code more readable and transform the model creation into a function (the whole map stepAIC part). But the glm2 function environment cannot read the modelfiller("y", 2, "x", "lag") argument. Is there a way how you can pass it from the outer function into the inner one?

Comment: @JulianStopp I'm not 100% sure I understand the issue. If you were to do `mdl <- str2lang(modelfiller("y", 2, "x", "lag"))` as in the answer, and then pass `mdl` to `glm2()`, it doesn't work for you?

Comment: That did not work until I've put mdl also into the glm2() definiton (glm2 <- function(.df, mdl, ...) ), only then it worked. Thanks a lot to your help!